# Who is not tall?

Tags: pronouns

Is it clear that my father is taller than my brother?

> My brother is just like my father, but **he** is not as tall.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear.  **My brother** is the subject of the sentence, so it's logical to assume that "he" refers to "my brother".

Comment: You can leave out the "he is" and still be just as clear: _My brother is just like my father, but not as tall._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentence

> My brother is just like my father, but *he* is not as tall.

"he" refers to your brother, ambiguity would be added if your sentence changed to

> My brother is just like my father, but *he* is not as tall as his friend.

in which case the "he" might refer to either your brother or your father being shorter than their friend, but since "your brother is *like* your father" both would be expected to be shorter than the friend.